# How do I uninstall and remove Drupal Console from my project?

Tags: 8, composer, console

1 year ago, I installed the Drupal Console module on my site.

This module seems to be completely abandoned, so I'm asking my question here.

https://www.drupal.org/project/console

I had installed this module with Composer and in my composer.json file I have this line :

```
"drupal/console": "~1.0"
```

In drupal `/admin/modules` I don't see any module with the name Console. How to remove this module ? Is it normal that there is nothing in Drupal ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal Console is not a Drupal module, is a shell for Drupal that is installed as a Composer package. This means it is not *installed* in Drupal so you don't have to uninstall it.

To remove it simply use `composer` and update your dependencies:

```
composer remove drupal/console
composer install
```

**Update**

You may also need to remove the Drupal Console Launcher if you have installed it. Drupal Console Launcher is an executable usually installed in your PATH that allows running Drupal Console without writing the complete path.

This process depends on the method used to install it. If you followed [standard installation process](https://drupalconsole.com/docs/en/getting/launcher) just remove the launcher deleting it (Keep in mind that Drupal Console is named `drupal`):

```
rm /usr/local/bin/drupal
```

You probably need to be root to do it.

If the launcher is not there try to locate it using `whereis`:

```
$ whereis drupal
drupal: /usr/bin/drupal
```

Once you locate the file just remove it.

Comment: It's not a module; it's a Composer package.

Comment: I guess when I say "is not a regular module" can be understood as "is a 'special' module". I'm updating the answer.

Comment: Yes, _not a regular module_ could be understand as _a module different from other modules_. The answer itself was correct. As written now, it avoids confusion between users. (There are already users who wonder why they don't see Drush in the list of modules.)

Comment: It would be good to also mention here how to remove the Drupal Console Launcher, which is the other half of the DC project.

Comment: Good point @Timmah. Answer updated.